# Policy cointains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'a' looking for beginning value

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to add a policy to my execution role so my lambda function can access my s3 buckets. So I created this `data` resource in terraform for the policy, which looks like this.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_s3_access" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:*Object"
    ]
    resources = [
      "${aws_s3_bucket.bronze-stage.arn}/*",
      "${aws_s3_bucket.silver-stage.arn}/*",
      "${aws_s3_bucket.gold-stage.arn}/*",
      "${aws_s3_bucket.bronze-stage.arn}",
      "${aws_s3_bucket.silver-stage.arn}",
      "${aws_s3_bucket.gold-stage.arn}"
    ]
  }
}
```

The json when I create the plan looks like this. (EDIT)

```
+ resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_s3_access_iam_policy" {
      + arn         = (known after apply)
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + name        = "lambda_s3_access"
      + name_prefix = (known after apply)
      + path        = "/"
      + policy      = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action   = [
                          + "s3:ListBucket",
                          + "s3:*Object",
                        ]
                      + Effect   = "Allow"
                      + Resource = [
                          + "arn:aws:s3:::silver-stage-bucket-test/*",
                          + "arn:aws:s3:::silver-stage-bucket-test",
                          + "arn:aws:s3:::gold-stage-bucket-test/*",
                          + "arn:aws:s3:::gold-stage-bucket-test",
                          + "arn:aws:s3:::bronze-stage-bucket-test/*",
                          + "arn:aws:s3:::bronze-stage-bucket-test",
                        ]
                      + Sid      = ""
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
      + policy_id   = (known after apply)
      + tags_all    = (known after apply)
    }
```

After that I create a policy resource from this data like this.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_s3_access_iam_policy" {
  name = "lambda_s3_access"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_s3_access.json
}
```

But when I use this policy resource I keep getting this error.

```
Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'a' looking for beginning of value
```

I have also tried creating the policy with the `EOF` syntax but without any luck. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see the JSON in the plan output? What does it look like?

Comment: I added it in my question.

Comment: Which version of TF are you using?  FYI: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9896

Comment: I'm using terrafomr version v1.4.5

Comment: Can you add `output "debugjson" { value = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_s3_access.json }` to your outputs & remove `lambda_s3_access_iam_policy` from your resources - i.e. so you can view the json generated without hitting the error; that may show if there's some bug in the json encoding.  Looks more like a bug with TF/AWS provider than with your code.

Comment: When I check the json from the debug output and test it in a json validator it says that it is a good json. So my guess also is that it is a bug from terraflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encounter this very same error. I did not find a terraform fix for this but what you can do is create a shell script which does the exact same, it creates the policy and then attaches it to the lambda execution role. I know this is probably not the best way to go about this but as this is a bug in terraform/aws I don't see a different way to go about this. Either way this is my solution.
This is my policy in json format

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my shell script which I call in my github actions.

```
#!/bin/bash

# create policy
output=$(aws iam create-policy --policy-name "access_s3_buckets" --policy-document file://bucket_access_policy.json)
arn_policy=$(echo $output | jq -r '.Policy.Arn')

aws iam attach-role-policy --role-name lambda_role --policy-arn $arn_policy
```

It firstly creates the policy and I store the json output, then I get the Arn from this output and use this to attach my policy to the lambda execution role (lambda_role). Hope this helps other  people with this error. And for those who use this solution don't forget to make your script executable in github actions. (`git update-index --chmod=+x script_name.sh`)

### EDIT

I have found a terraform fix for this problem.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_role_s3_bucket" {
  name = "lambda_access_s3_buckets"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllBucketActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Bucket",
            "Resource": [
                "${aws_s3_bucket.bronze-stage.arn}",
                "${aws_s3_bucket.silver-stage.arn}",
                "${aws_s3_bucket.gold-stage.arn}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": [
                "${aws_s3_bucket.bronze-stage.arn}/*",
                "${aws_s3_bucket.silver-stage.arn}/*",
                "${aws_s3_bucket.gold-stage.arn}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Create your policy in plain text like this.

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_s3_access_attachment" {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_role.name}"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_role_s3_bucket.arn
}
```

And then you can attach it to your execution role like this.

I'll leave both my answers in here. Hope this helps other people!